# In Appian, I have created a process model. In that approve, reject, and screening action is involved

Tags: process, mapping

In Appian, I have created a process model. In that approve, reject, and screening action is involved. I am taking decisions for each action. If the decision is true for any of the actions I am finishing the process. Or else it will return back to the main form. And also I want to print the appropriate error there and then back to the main form. But I am not getting the error. And it is finishing the process itself.

I am expecting to print an error and it should return to the main form. But because the screening node and approve node are crossing each other for that reason only I think I am not getting proper results.

How can I implement that?